# Exception while running query on Apache Phoenix API

Tags: mysql, apache-phoenix

while running below query from Apache Phoenix Query,

```
select * from TABLE1 where PK like 'foo_bar_foo_bar_%' and COLUMN1 = '1' and  COLUMN2 = 'true' order by UPPER(COLUMN3) desc limit 50 offset 0
```

getting below error,

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Let me know if I am missing anything here. My initial analysis is that issue is with UPPER().

**Note:** Same command works on Phoenix Shell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was an issue with UPPER() from the query. After adding proper Jars to code it worked.